# MVVM ViewModel and child Views

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contentcontrol

I'm building an MVVM WPF application, in which there's a wizard with multiple Child Views loaded in a parent View (V) that uses ViewModel (VM) as its data context. One of the MVVM pattern principles states that the VM should not have any knowledge of the V that is bound to it. In this case, VM indeed is not aware of the V, however, the VM (1) manages a list property consisting of different child Views (i.e. different steps), and (2) has another property named `CurrentView` to dynamically be assigned with an element in the list. `CurrentView` is bound to a `ContentControl` in V.

My questions are:

1. Is is okay to manage (child) Views inside the VM? In other words, the VM does not know about the parent V, but knows which child Views are to be loaded.
2. Instead of use different child VM for different child Views, I just bind a single parent VM to the parent V, and when a child V is loaded, it can share the same data context with the containing parent V. Is this the right way to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parent view model should have knowledge of the child **view models**, not the child **views**. Likewise, the parent **view**, not the **view model**, should be responsible for switching out the child views.

Here's how you might go about this...

In your view, create some data templates, like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:WizardScreen1ViewModel}">
        <v:WizardScreen1 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:WizardScreen2ViewModel}">
        <v:WizardScreen2 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:WizardScreen3ViewModel}">
        <v:WizardScreen3 />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then, in the part of your view where you display the current wizard screen, put a `ContentControl`, like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentWizardScreenViewModel}" />
```

In your parent view model, you will need a `CurrentWizardScreenViewModel` property that fires a `PropertyChanged` event when it changes.

Then, you need your wizard's next/previous buttons to bind to commands in your parent view model that cause `CurrentWizardScreenViewModel` to be set to the next/previous screen's view model.

If you do this, the view will automatically take care of switching out the wizard screen view thanks to the magic of data binding.

Comment: Should I let the child VMs to manage their own data, which might be shared between them (i.e. step 3 might need something from step 1), or just handle everything in the parent VM?

Comment: @tab87vn, There are a couple ways you go with that: (1) have the parent view model manage/orchestrate the shared state by listening for change notifications on each of the child view models, then informing the other child view models of the new state or (2) you could leave the parent view model out of it and just have the child view models talk to each other directly using a messenger (which most MVVM libraries support).